# DB2 Xml Extract into columns

Tags: db2, db2-400, db2-luw

I'm having these kind of xml,with nearly 100 tags.
Extract these xml into columns,

```
<root><care>123</care><look>test</look><see>type</see></root>
```

My Expected Result:

```
 care   look   see
  123    test  type
```

Have these Example,but it will work depends upon columns mapping,
i'm having nearly 100 tags,

```
SELECT X.care,
                 X.look                
          FROM (SELECT <root><care>123</care><look>test</look><see>type</see></root> AS care_test FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1)
               AS A,
               XMLTABLE (
                  '$d/row'
                  PASSING care_test AS "d"
                  COLUMNS care  VARCHAR (10)
                             PATH 'care',
                          look VARCHAR (10)
                             PATH 'look',
                               see VARCHAR (10)
                             PATH 'see') AS X;
```

Comment: So, what's the problem with your query? Doesn't it return the result you expect?

Comment: Yes,Without column mapping need my expected result(Which means in that query im passing 'care','look','see' - these are the columns i need,but without those need the expected query)

Comment: The SQL standard requires the mapping. So what is your question?

Comment: I'm having nearly 150 tags for all need to map? and also sometime  when executing that time tags may varies.So without Map need to Extract into columns

Comment: Yes, you have to map all the columns you want in a SELECT list. Not all 150 elements (there is no such meaning in XML as "tag"), but only needed ones. Db2 must know the row structure you want to get beforehand, and you can't make Db2 understand it during runtime. BTW, what does it mean "I'm having nearly 150 elements"? Where do you have it? In a table column? As a parameter? Somehow else?